# Get the last and the previous "gold_id" of the previous day with mongo

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this kind of data :

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('560b5c5d80ec9700030035dc'), "active"=>true, "user_id"=>nil, "action"=>"connection", "shop_id"=>245929, "gold_id"=>23452349, "indexed"=>true, "created_at"=>2015-09-30 03:51:57 UTC}
```

I'm trying to get the first and last `gold_id` of the previous day. I'm getting arroung 10_000 logs per days.

I'm using the ruby driver

```
  first_gold_in = Time.utc(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, (Date.today.day - 1), 00, 00)
  first_gold_out = yesterday_o_clock + 5*60
  first_gold_id = logs
    .find("action" => "connection", "created_at" => {"$gte" => first_gold_in, "$lte" => first_gold_out} )
    .first
    .fetch("gold_id")

  last_gold_in = Time.utc(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, (Date.today.day - 1), 23, 55)
  last_gold_out = yesterday_o_clock + 5*60 - 1
  last_gold_id = logs
    .find("action" => "connection", "created_at" => {"$gte" => last_gold_in, "$lte" => last_gold_out} )
    .first
    .fetch("gold_id")
```

But It's very slow even with shorter date range. Is there a better way to do it?
Also is is possible to get the first and the last of the day in the same request?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `.where` instead of `.find`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh `undefined method 'where' for #<Mongo::Collection:0x007ffaa4821e18> (NoMethodError)` :)

Comment: Oh. My bad. I thought this was `mongoid`.